# Create family of objects depends on a string or enum violates Open - Closed principle

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am developing a library to convert HTML document as word document. This is done by traversing through the HTML document and process the HTML elements one by one. There are family of classes to process each HTML tag.

```
public abstract class DocxElement
{
   public void Process();
}

public class DocxTable : DocxElement
{
   public override void Process(){}
}

public class DocxDiv : DocxElement
{
  public override void Process(){}
}
```

The above classes are responsible to process its html counterpart. So whenever I expand the library to support an additional html tag, I will just create a sub class from DocxElement. The html parser uses a factory class to generate concerate DocxElement class whenever it meets an HTML tag.

```
public class ElementFactory
{

  public DocxElement Resolve(string htmlTag)
  {
     switch(htmlTag)
     {
        case "table":
         return new DocxTable();

        case "div":
         return new DocxDiv();
     }
  }
}
```

Now I feel it violates the Open closed principle. I prefer not to use reflection just because of design patterns require that. So I created a singleton dictionary to register the element classes.

```
Dictionary<string, Func<DocxElement>> doc;

doc.Add("table",()=>{ new DocxTable();});
```

Finally I was able to eliminate the switch statement. Still I need to add elements to the dictionary when I create a new sub class.

Is there any better method to do this? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your `Dictionary` method is fine. Anything else trying to make this generic will lose the static compile time checking. If you're ready to sacrifice the compile time checking, you can use reflection to make this code generic.

```
public class ElementFactory
{
    public DocxElement Resolve(string htmlTag)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.Docx{1}",
            typeof(ElementFactory).Namespace,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(htmlTag)));
        return (DocxElement)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
ElementFactory factory = new ElementFactory();
var table = factory.Resolve("table");//Works
var div = factory.Resolve("div");//Works
var span = factory.Resolve("span");//Explodes!!
```

As you can see this can fail a runtime for several reasons. Type not found, Type found but no public parameterless constructor, Type found but it doesn't derive from `DocxElement`, etc etc..

So it is better you can stick with `Dictionary` option IMO.